# Setting up a proxy that authenticates at a remote server

Tags: authentication, reverse-proxy, remote-access

my problem is as follows:

We have an account at a remote service, which is not under our control. Login seems to work with HTTP digest (probably also basic, but that's less cool). Since the service is a bit restricted, we would like to share our account with a few selected people. However, rather than giving them our credentials, we would like to set up a proxy server at one of our servers, which these people can then reach, using our own authentication. So, the problem is: our proxy must take the requests, and do the authentication at the remote service. Most information I find is, how to require people to authenticate at the proxy, but I want the proxy to log in at the remote service. Is there a way to do that with apache, squid, or any other tool?

Regards,
Claus

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at Adito - http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-als/. It should accomplish what you have described.